# How to write tests against code requiring remote OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I have some code that uses an API to push some data to a remote third-party service.

In actual use, it needs OAuth-generated credentials to push to this API endpoint. That's all working, when the user pushes the 'export' button, we redirect them through the OAuth flow, they come back, we've got a token, we push the data (probably in a bg job, which has it's own potential problems, but that's not the focus of this question), great.

But how do I write an automated test for this functionality? I don't have the OAuth credentials at test time, and I don't know if there's any good way to get them.

I *could* actually web scrape to fake a user login to real third-party service, but that seems ugly. I could skip the actual "prove it really pushes test", and just test that the request I'm going to send *looks* right, but I'd love to have an automated test proving that it really does succesfully push, in case the third party changes things. I *would* probably record it with "vcr" to avoid the slow network requests each time, but that's not the issue either (unless it is because it'll make things even harder...)

In this case, the third-party API uses OAuth 1.0a, if that matters.

Any ideas or solutions? Is this a thing?

Answer (score 0):

OmniAuth has a built in test mode that can be used to short-circuit the actual requests.

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

You can simulate a failure with:

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:some_provider] = :invalid_credentials
```

Or setup a response with:

```
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:some_provider, {:uid => '12345'})
```

You would only really do this in tests which cover the authentication system, such as your `CallbacksController` or integration tests that cover the sign in path.

For everything else you would just stub out the authentication system so that your `current_user` returns a fixture (or factory) when there should be an authenticated user. Its a lot faster than each integration test retesting the same sign pathway. (click "sign in" ...)

If you are using Warden or Devise they have built in test helpers to do this.

You could record it with VCR, but that introduces issues of what to do with cassettes that might potentially contain sensitive information and how those should be shared between developers.

Usually testing against the actual provider is more of a OmniAuth strategy author concern that you don't need to worry about unless you are creating a strategy for some obscure OAuth provider or creating an OAuth service of your own. If you are using Facebook, Twitter or one of the other big boys then its not a concern.

See also:

- https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara
- https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Testing

This is an example of an integration test from a project that uses [omniauth-flickr](https://github.com/timbreitkreutz/omniauth-flickr):

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/omniauth'

RSpec.feature 'Flickr Authentication' do

  let(:t) { I18n.t }
  let(:sign_in_via_flickr) do
    visit root_path
    click_link t('sessions.menu.sign_in_with_flickr')
  end

  context 'with a successfull flickr auth' do
    before do
       # mock_auth_hash is helper which returns a big hash of fake user data
       OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:flickr, mock_auth_hash)
       OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:flickr]
    end
    scenario 'when I click log in, I should be logged in via Flickr' do
      sign_in_via_flickr
      expect(page).to have_content t('sessions.flash.you_have_been_signed_in')
    end
    scenario 'I should be logged out' do
      sign_in_via_flickr
      click_link(t('sessions.menu.sign_out'))
      expect(page).to have_content t('sessions.flash.you_have_been_signed_out')
    end
  end
  context 'with a failed authentication' do
    before do
      OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:flickr] = :invalid_credentials
    end
    scenario 'I should be notified that sign in failed' do
      sign_in_via_flickr
      expect(page).to have_content t('auth.failure.flashes.invalid_credentials')
    end
    scenario 'I should not be logged in' do
      sign_in_via_flickr
      expect(page).to_not have_content(t('sessions.flash.you_have_been_signed_in'))
      expect(page).to_not have_link(t('sessions.menu.sign_out'))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not just using OAuth for logging users in. I am calling an API that requires OAuth authentication to work. Ideally I'd like to have a test that verifies my API call works. I'm also not using OmniAuth, although this still gives me ideas of what to stub. But if I stub the entire API call... I'm not actually verifying it works. Ideally I want to do something I can record with VCR, that actually tests that the API call worked.